# Grouping identically structured datasets working on one but not the other

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse

#### The Error

```
Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `rel_hedge_booster_score = paste(breaks[-length(breaks)], breaks[-1], sep = " to ")`.
Caused by error:
! `rel_hedge_booster_score` must be size 11 or 1, not 10.
```

#### The Data

For the question I will refer to 2 of my data frames. `aus_pol_data` which the current code works on & `cas_uk_data` which causes the error given above.

Both of these are structured in EXACTLY the same way. They have different values of course since they are different datasets, but all the columns and variable types align. [This is an important column, because the grouping/breaks are based upon this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gjhjt.png). This `rel_hedge_booster_score` is a numeric value that ranges from -100 to 100. Both of the datasets have many rows with a value in between these as well as -100 and 100 themselves.

#### Where the error occurs

`breaks <<- seq(-100, 100, by = 20)` is defined outside of the below functions and used by both.

```
  df_aus_pol_karma <<- aus_pol_data %>%
    mutate(range_label = cut(rel_hedge_booster_score, breaks = breaks, labels = FALSE, right = FALSE)) %>%
    group_by(range_label) %>%
    summarize(
      num_data_points = n(),
      median_karma_score = median(karma_score),
      mean_karma_score = mean(karma_score),
      karma_scores = list(karma_score)
    ) %>%
    mutate(rel_hedge_booster_score = paste(breaks[-length(breaks)], breaks[-1], sep = " to ")) %>%
    select(rel_hedge_booster_score, num_data_points, median_karma_score, mean_karma_score)
```

[This part works and creates exactly what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8W4jZ.png). The grouping can be seen here.

```
  df_cas_uk_karma <<- cas_uk_data %>%
    mutate(range_label = cut(rel_hedge_booster_score, breaks = breaks, labels = FALSE, right = FALSE)) %>%
    group_by(range_label) %>%
    summarize(
      num_data_points = n(),
      median_karma_score = median(karma_score),
      mean_karma_score = mean(karma_score),
      karma_scores = list(karma_score)
    ) %>%
    mutate(rel_hedge_booster_score = paste(breaks[-length(breaks)], breaks[-1], sep = " to ")) %>%
    select(rel_hedge_booster_score, num_data_points, median_karma_score, mean_karma_score)
```

This causes the above error, even though nothing is different but the name of the dataset. When running through the code step by step, it seems the error occurs at the `mutate(rel_hedge_booster_score = paste(breaks[-length(breaks)], breaks[-1], sep = " to "))` line. If I look at what's happened up until that point for both of the datasets I notice that `df_cas_uk_karma` has one more observation than `df_aus_pol_karma`. Compare [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fY8Jk.png) with [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYhiy.png).

EDIT: And I notice now that the groupings are also a bit weird (0 to 20, 20 to 40...) something's off there as well. All the data is in there correctly though (the total number of data points is the same as in the dataset), so it's just a visual thing)

#### Solution (See answer below, thank you!)

```
  df_cas_uk_karma_table_data <<- cas_uk_data %>%
    mutate(rel_hedge_booster_score = cut(rel_hedge_booster_score, breaks = breaks, labels = paste(breaks[-length(breaks)], breaks[-1], sep = " to "), right = FALSE)) %>%
    group_by(rel_hedge_booster_score) %>%
    summarize(
      num_data_points = n(),
      median_karma_score = median(karma_score),
      mean_karma_score = mean(karma_score),
      karma_scores = list(karma_score)
    ) %>%
    select(rel_hedge_booster_score, num_data_points, median_karma_score, mean_karma_score)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

up at the top you create the groupings

```
 cut(rel_hedge_booster_score, breaks = breaks, labels = FALSE, right = FALSE))
```

then you group by, summarise, and try to relabel the groupings. Yet, the way you have done so is not-robust, it requires every group for which there is a label to have one example in the summary input, and it also requires that the data be correctly ordered.
It would be much wise to simply use your code that creates the labels (pasting from the breaks) as the label parameter of cut ... rather than labels=FALSE

```
 cut(rel_hedge_booster_score, breaks = breaks, labels =  paste(breaks[-length(breaks)], breaks[-1], sep = " to "), right = FALSE))
```

Comment: I've replaced my `cut(...)` with ` mutate(range_label = cut(rel_hedge_booster_score, breaks = breaks, labels =  paste(breaks[-length(breaks)], breaks[-1], sep = " to "), right = FALSE))` and it still works on `aus_pol` but the same error persists on other datasets. I don't fully understand your idea, so I hope I am doing it correctly.

Comment: I'm skeptical that my solution would fail in the way you describe; though I'm open to the possibility. please provide a reproducible example if you would like my continued assistance in this matter.

Comment: The results are exactly the same. I don't really know how to provide a reproducible example without providing a sample of the dataset. The code I now ran can be seen here: https://pastebin.com/XZ57m9uu . I made no other adjustments (other than the name of df). 

When I go through the code step by step, the same thing also happens after `summarize()`, where `df_cas_uk_karma_table_data`  has 11 observations, but `df_aus_pol_karma_table_data` has 10. 

It is of course possible that I am doing it wrong.

Comment: how many times are you mutating with a paste of breaks ? my suggestion was moving where you used to do it to an earlier position, the cut. you are required to not do it later i.e not after the cut. its unclear that you moved it, perhaps you are simply repeating yourself. its the late application of it that is the problem

Comment: Thanks for your help! I now understand what the problem was.  I'll edit my post with the solution.